# No devices found with name or id matching 'emulator-5554'

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am trying to run flutter on android studio and I keep getting this error despite having created a virtual device. Please help.

Comment: Please add the output of `flutter doctor -v` and `flutter devices`

Comment: how did u slove this issue

Answer (score 0):

**How I solve this in VSCode**

Go to in your **terminal of the IDE** (Android Studio or Visual Studio Code), and type **flutter doctor** and check if one of the dependences is missing.

In my case is the 'Android SDK reference is missing', fix it with: *'flutter config --android-sdk '* and run *'flutter doctor -v.'*

I hope this work for you :)

Follow me on Github @brunomarcosluz